# Gradle - Invoke another plugins task from a task in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am planning to use [palantir docker plugin](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker) to download a docker image. From the [doc](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker), I understood how to include above plugin

```
plugins {
    id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.26.0"
} 
docker {
.....
}
```

Now my `build.gradle` has a task `ABC` and in that task I should call the above `docker` task.
I tried something as a `task` calling another `task` but did not work. Could someone please suggest the rightway to invoke the `docker` block from my task.

```
task ABC(type: Customtest) {
   dependsOn docker
.......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `dependsOn docker`, I used `dependsOn getTasksByName("docker", false)` and it worked fine